service in init.target.rc is never called within AOSP . Is this a SELINUX problem?
Below is the service that I would like to call on init.target.rc in AOSP for sdm710 product.
service dispBridge /system/bin/test.sh
    seclabel u:r:init:s0
    user root
    group root
    oneshot
    disabled
    write /dev/kmsg "dispBridgeServiceStartedTest onBootTest"



on boot
    chown system system /sys/class/leds/red/blink
    chown system system /sys/class/leds/green/blink
    chown system system /sys/class/leds/blue/blink
    write /dev/kmsg "onBootTest1"
    start dispBridge
    write /dev/kmsg "onBootTest2"

In the code above, I am expecting the service would be called within on boot, and expect to see dispBridgeServiceStartedTest onBootTest printed out in adb shell.
However, I can only see onBootTest1 and onBootTest2 printed out, which means that dispBridgeServiceStartedTest onBootTest must have been skipped/ service was not called.
I have tried setting the androidboot.selinux=permissive on BoardConfig.mk,
and seclabel u:r:init:s0 , according to Android run script at boot using init.rc not working.
I tried to manually start the service on adb shell with start dispBridge, and this is the output using adb shell dmesg -w | grep dispBridge
[  271.108234] init: Received control message 'start' for 'dispBridge' from pid: 2606 (start dispBridge)
[  271.109119] init: starting service 'dispBridge'...
[  271.132498] init: Service 'dispBridge' (pid 2607) exited with status 127
[ 3069.662302] init: Received control message 'start' for 'dispBridge' from pid: 5640 (start dispBridge)
[ 3069.662771] init: starting service 'dispBridge'...
[ 3069.716114] init: Service 'dispBridge' (pid 5641) exited with status 127


and when i use dmesg | grep -i "avc: denied"
[  271.122590] type=1400 audit(1730388931.839:21): avc: denied { entrypoint } for pid=2607 comm="init" path="/system/bin/test.sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1215 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
[ 3069.693749] type=1400 audit(1730388931.839:21): avc: denied { entrypoint } for pid=2607 comm="init" path="/system/bin/test.sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1215 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
[ 3069.694039] type=1400 audit(1730391730.409:22): avc: denied { entrypoint } for pid=5641 comm="init" path="/system/bin/test.sh" dev="dm-0" ino=1215 scontext=u:r:shell:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:system_file:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Referencing init warning: Service myservice needs a SELinux domain defined. Please fix, I tried running this command
ls -Z /system/bin/test.sh  
and this is the output
u:object_r:system_file:s0 /system/bin/test.sh

I am also not sure if a .te file is required for me to set the permissions, but I have also tried androidboot.selinux=disabled, and the service still did not run.
May I seek assistance to point me in the right direction , to enable this service? I am not really sure what is the problem and I am honestly lost in how to proceed onwards as I am new to this. Thank you in advance!

I recommend isolating variables and introducing complexity one step at a time. SELinux is one of the more complex areas of Android but luckily AOSP is open source so there are plenty of examples to follow.
Read the section "Label new services and address denials" on the "Write SELinux policy" page on the AOSP site here: https://source.android.com/docs/security/features/selinux/device-policy#label_new_services_and_address_denials This section will explain how to create a new domain for your app and ensure that it transitions when init starts it (in which case you won't need to use seclabel in your init rc file).
Start with a native app instead of a shell script since shell scripts introduce another variable: the shell binary. The native app should just do something like print "Hello world" and sleep in a loop, then you can verify the app at least starts running. Once you have go that working you can introduce accessing some resources, which will also require adding SELinux rules.
Here is a random example I found of SELinux rules for a service that is started by init: https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:system/sepolicy/vendor/hal_gnss_default.te
Generally none of the init services in pure AOSP are shell scripts. Vendors like Qualcomm tend to use shell scripts during init but it's a little more complex so I would recommend against it unless you are working on a project where init shell scripts are already in use in which case you can follow their examples.

You need to add sepolicy rules for your service for sure!
Check out similar example:
Run shell script at boot in AOSP
